# How to fix the Data error (cyclic redundancy check) on a smartphone?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, chkdsk, mtp

I regularly transfer data from my (Android) smartphone to my (Windows 10) PC / NAS. For that I simply connect th ePC and the smartphone via USB and cut&paste the files to the PC or directly to the NAS (shared folder, that is permanently mounted on my PC).

Now I'm getting this error:

> Error Moving File or Folder
> Data error (cyclic redundancy check)

[image: Error Moving File or Folder - Data error (cyclic redundancy check)]

Sometimes it works, when I try it again and again.

A common solution for this error seems to be the running of the `chkdsk /r`. But in my case it's not applicable, since the smartphone is mounted vie MTP and is not accessible via command line.

**What might have cause this issue? How to get it working correctly again?**

Comment: Try replacing your USB cable. I think its broken. Make sure its a data/power cable, not a power only cable.

Comment: If it's not the cable, then some disk is in a bad shape. The question is whether this is the disk in the phone or in the computer. You might have a look at the SMART attributes of the computer disk, since the phone's is not easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

### What might have caused this issue?

The cyclic redundancy check (CRC) error typically indicates that there may be issues with the integrity of the data being transferred. This error can occur due to various reasons, such as corrupted files, hardware problems, or issues with the file system.

### How to get it working correctly again?

Start with some simple fix.

- Instead of transferring a large number of files at once, try transferring them in smaller batches. This can help identify if the issue is specific to certain files.
- Make sure that the drivers for your Android device are up to date on your Windows 10 PC. Outdated drivers can sometimes cause file transfer issues.
- Ensure that the USB cable you are using is in good condition. Try using a different USB cable or USB port on your PC to rule out any hardware issues.

If you can't run the chkdsk /r command  via command line, you can  check for file system errors by right-clicking on the drive, selecting "Properties," going to the "Tools" tab, and clicking "Check."

If MTP is causing issues, you might consider using alternative methods for file transfer, such as Wi-Fi file transfer apps, cloud storage, or a microSD card if your smartphone supports one.